Java advice wanted: "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection" caused by "HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out"
the situation: I am working on a java server application, on linux, java 11, jpa, hikari, mssql database. I have several parts of my application that uses entitymanager's createNativeQuery and createStoredProcedureQuery and after each of these I remember to call entityManager.close(), I also use SQLServerBulkCopy to bulk copy rows into tables, for this I use the a wrapped implementation named bytefish.jsqlserverbulkinsert, to use this I have to provide a connection and these connections is normal java.sql.connection objects, that are opened prior to bulk copying and after which commit and close is called. these connections are handled and reused in a connection pool.
the problem: under heavy load some sql connection resource is exhausted and all following attempts to use a connection anywhere will return this exception:
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
caused by:
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
I thought that remembering to close the connections and the entitymanagers where they are used, even in case of an exception, would ensure that the connections was left ready for use an other time. what am i missing?
edit: The database is accessed by other application and management studio with out problems simultaneous with this problem, so I dont think the db is self is the problem, maybe there is a per-user maximum number of connections?

Should should probably start with the most authoritative source - the db, firstly checking whether you have maxed out. If you haven't there might be some other problem with the pool

@g00se thanks for your answer, I will do some googling regarding your answer. I have also added my immidiate thoughts in an edit of the question

I don't know if there's a 'max per user' thing going on - I suspect not. But if it doesn't look suspicious at the MySql server then I would turn on debugging for the pool and see what's happening

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

@aled sorry but I dont think this is possible, its a periodic problem and a big system, it only occurs under conditions which I think is heavy load, but I dont really know what triggers this. if interesting I can show code snippets, but a reproducible example is going to be difficult

@g00se thanks. yes. if I could get the hikary framework to provide more information than just "Connection is not available, request timed out" that would be great. I will look into it

I recommend to read How to Ask.

check out select * from sys.sysprocesses and see if there's any stuff lying around which belongs to your app. Perhaps you have a very small pool of connections?

@siggemannen thanks. I will do that next time I have this problem, try that sql. my pool is setup to 30 connections so should be ok I would think as I shouldn't be running that fast through the connections. there is a thread that collects sql work and bulk copies it in.
